# JavaFX analog of Swing Action

Tags: java, swing, javafx-2

In Swing application i can declare an [Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html) object which allows to maintain:

- action availability
- accelerator key
- what action do

and other things in single place.

Let me dive you into some details:

I'm having a scene with `TreeView`. 
In scene i have some buttons which allows to add child and remove selected item.

Additionaly i'm having an `ContextMenu` for `TreeView` with `MenuItem`'s which does same things as a buttons.

Depending on selected item i need to enable or disable those menu items and buttons.

In Swing i can solve this easily by using Swing Action. 
I.e. enabling/disabling action will enable/disable all associated components.

Does JavaFX 2.2 has some analog of Swing Action?

Comment: I know only about the `*.setOnAction(EventHandler)` method which is the analog of `*.addActionListener()` in Swing.

Comment: It does have an [ActionEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/event/ActionEvent.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No. JavaFX 2.2 does not have an equivalent to Action. There is an extension project called ControlsFX that offers action classes, but is designed to work with JavaFX 8.

That being said, it should be easy enough to implement at least a workable alternative. Basically, I'd write my own Action class exposing an ObservableBooleanValue (or in your case probably a BooleanBinding) and bind the controls' disable property to it to mimic Swings enabled state. It is a bit more cumbersome, but with a few lines of utility methods you'll at least get close.